# Copying raw text from a grep to paste in an email

Tags: grep, debian, virtual-machine

I'm running a VM with Debian 7.0 x64 and need to troubleshoot something with a provider, so when I run a grep command, the console outputs a long report. I need to copy all of that text that has been output and place in the body of an email, or post directly on another forum board. I'm sure the solution must be simple, but I can't find it in searching online. I see suggestions for right-clicking with the mouse but my VM console doesn't response to mouse clicks, and then I see suggestions for copying and modifying files within the console, but as I said above I just need to take the raw text to paste elsewhere.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way would be to save the output to a file and attach that to your email. (personally i hate emails that have inlined long error-logs without good cuase - like annotations).
this would also allow you to compress the file before attaching it, reducing the size considerably (as text compresses quite nicely).

if this is not an option, there is `xclip`, which reads from stdin and puts that into a selection.

```
$ ls | xclip
```

allows you to paste (with your middle-mousebutton) the contents of a dir.

if you must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> for pasting, you can also do:

```
$ ls | xclip -selection c
```

Comment: thanks so much! If you happen to check back here and have a few minutes, could you give me the line by line commands that I would need to input to save the complete output to a file? Sorry, real rookie here!!

Comment: Just pipe the output of your grep command into `xclip`. (I really cannot be more specific as I don't know what you do to create your output).

Comment: also there is no point in writing "if you happen to check back..." as this is the same as saying "if you happen to read these lines". if i don't, i won't be able to react on your comments.